# check if user exist in php

Tags: php, if-statement, rows

I got following code to check if the username exist

```
$klassegruppe = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['opretklassegruppe']);
    $kodeord = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['opretkodeord']);

    $check = "SELECT klassegruppe FROM klassegrupper WHERE klassegruppe = '". $klassegruppe ."'";
    $navnecheck = mysqli_query($conn,$check);

      if (mysql_num_rows($navnecheck) != 0) { 

        header("Location: http://klassegruppen.dk/?fejl=2&navn=". $klassegruppe ."");

        $conn->close();

      } 

      if (mysql_num_rows($navnecheck) == 0) {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO klassegrupper (klassegruppe, kodeord) 
        VALUES ('". $klassegruppe ."', '". $kodeord ."')";

        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {}

        $conn->close();

        header('Location: http://klassegruppen.dk/?oprettet=1');

      }
```

Running this code its like the query doesn't get any values. It just keeps adding usernames to the database, even if it does exists

Answer (score 5):

You're mixing MySQL APIs using `mysql_num_rows`.

Use `mysqli_num_rows` with the added `i`.

Those different APIs do not intermix with each other.

Comment: omg.. this worked.. i didnt see that.. Ill accept the answer when i can in 12 minutes.